# Run custom "clock" / DateTime.now c#

Tags: c#, datetime, clock

I need to simulate a clock that is fairly precise. I need some kind of DateTime.Now, not for the local time, but for a web server's time(which can differ a few seconds from system time).

The thing is I need to be accurate, even 3 seconds is way too much difference. 
Any way to create a DateTime object and then "let it run" so it shows the current server time?

PS: Not talking about a time server, but a normal web server. Can I avoid setting the system time to server time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` is not very accurate, especially not for measuring time differences. »Letting it run« suggests that you actually want to use a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and a separate `DateTime` as starting time. You can then generate a current timestamp by just adding your start time and the elapsed time of the `Stopwatch`.

Comment: You can easily encapsulate that in a `Clock` class, of course.

Comment: Can you take a look at the ServerTime class below? This is what I came up with.

Comment: @philn: There's codereview.stackexchange for that sort of thing. But in this case: Make it a `static class`, make the `Stopwatch` `readonly`, use `Restart` instead of `Reset` and `Start`. `DateTime` is a `struct` and cannot be `null`, so make it a `DateTime?` instead. I'd probably use `basetime + swatch.Elapsed` instead of the `Add` call.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I have come up with:

```
public class ServerTime
{
    public static DateTime Now
    {
        get
        {
            if (baseTime != null)
                return baseTime.Add(swatch.Elapsed);
            else
                return DateTime.Now;
        }
        set
        {
            baseTime = value;
            swatch.Reset();
            swatch.Start();
        }
    }

    private static DateTime baseTime;
    private static Stopwatch swatch = new Stopwatch();

}
```

Not really sure how to handle ServerTime.Now if the baseTime was not set yet. 
I would probably never call this property before it was set, but as always: Don't trust your own code.